# Using Java 8, How to set a String Constant for obj[4] in a List<Object[]> if and only if it has null value?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I am getting resultSet which has 6 columns. Now, I am assigning that to List of Object Array. Fact is **Object[4]  of each object** in the list **may or may not be null**.
If it is having null value, I have to set the same with "System", a String constant value.
How to do that using **Java 8** ? Please assist!

```
List<Object[]> loanEntries = loanDAO.getLoanMappingDetails(QueryConstants.LOAN_MAPPING);
```

Comment: What does that DAO look like?  Either set it in there, or use a loop and an if statement in your code (but that'll introduce overhead - avoid unnecessary loops if you can).

Comment: Yes. I can do that using  'for' loop with 'if' statement to check for null, then setting the string value. But, I want to do it using forEach. Just one line statement. Please give the syntax!

Comment: See example 2.2 - https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But, I dint got exact solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that **loanEntries** is the variable you are talking about.

```
List<Object[]> loanEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        loanEntries.add(new Object[]{"a","b","c","d",null,"f"});
        loanEntries.add(new Object[]{"aa","bb","cc","dd",null,"ff"});

        loanEntries.stream()
                .filter(objects -> objects[4] == null)
                .forEach(objects -> objects[4] = "System");

        loanEntries.stream()
                .forEach(objects -> {
                    for (Object object : objects) {
                        System.out.println(object);
                    }
                });
```

**output**

```
a
b
c
d
System
f
aa
bb
cc
dd
System
ff
```

Comment: @BHAVANI SINGH, the main list 'loanEntries' remains the same after this code. I want the list to have 'System' values for those Objects which had object[4] as null.

Comment: @Karthiksa it's seems to be working, I have posted the output, please check. Are you asking to replace the entire Object[] with **System**, instead of just Object[4]

Comment: It will work. Because Object array is mutable. And it is also evident as @BHAWANISINGH printed the output

Comment: `loanEntries.stream().forEach(o ->  {
   if(o[4] == null) o[4] = "System";
  });`

Comment: I was using left join to fetch resultSet. Thought that unmatched records would give null value for object[6] i.e., for 5th column. But, the fact was, query contained concatenation of two string which resulted in white space instead of null. I replaced the null check with  **userEntries.stream().forEach(o -> { if(o[4].toString().matches("^\\s*$")) o[4] = "System"; });**  it is working fine. Thanks for the solution! @BHAWANI SINGH